# iOS 12: Could not instantiate class named WKWebView

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project created with **Xcode 12.4**.
The project must support iOS versions going back to **iOS 11.**

The app runs flawlessly with the **iOS 14 simulator**.
I downloaded the **iOS 12 simulator** in Xcode and when I run the app, it throws the following error:

```
Could not instantiate class named WKWebView because no class named WKWebView was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)
```

I added the WebKit framework in the **Link Binary With Libraries** section in the Build Phases.
I can only add WebKit from the **iOS 14 SDK** though (as the iOS 12 SDK doesn't come with Xcode 12)

So now I got a new error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

**Any idea what I should do here?**